# WKWebView observe cookies changes

Tags: cookies, wkwebview

According to wwdc 17 there is a way to observe cookies changes in WKWebView in iOs 11 (WebsiteDataStore.httpCookieStore).

Could you provide example how to do that?

I found that there is WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver and it has cookiesDidChange member.

So i put that protocol as following

```
class ActivitiesViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver {
```

and

```
func cookiesDidChange(in cookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore) {
```

but cookiesDidChange not fires (

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must add the view controller as an observer of the web data store to trigger the cookiesDidChange(in:) method.

```
// These two lines occur in the viewDidLoad method of a UIViewController class  
// This view controller conforms to the WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver protocol

WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.add(self)  
let webView = WKWebView()  

// Configure and load the web view
```

Note: In iOS 11.3 a change occurred that requires the `WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.add(self)` line to occur before the WKWebView object is created.

Comment: What's the source of this information about the change in 11.3? I'm seeing a problem where `cookiesDidChange` is called at first and then stops getting called.

Comment: This helped me. I had an issue where the cookies were not "properly" set/sniffed until the "next try", meaning I had to try to open the same webview a few times until it would detect cookies instantly. I had a thing in the opened webpage called in body onload which would call back to app code and from there close the webview - way too early for cookies to be set/detected. It all started to set cookies more early/properly when I added the cookie store observer *before* creating the wkwebview instance as noted in this answer.